How do I create CSS gradients that follow the square root average?
This question stems from this minutephysics video I watched a while back: Computer Color is Broken
It describes how the correct way to blend colors is to use the square root of the average of the squares of the R, G and B values, rather than simply taking the average.
So I was curious and decided to test how CSS implements gradients with a simple Red - Green gradient:


div {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(0,255,0), rgb(255,0,0));
}
<div></div>




As you can see, the gradient is kind of ugly, with dark yellow in the middle.
I decided to implement the correct gradient using gradient stops that follow the sqrt curve, and the result is definitely better:


div {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, 
        rgb(000,255,000),
        rgb(127,221,000) 25%,
        rgb(180,180,000) 50%,
        rgb(221,127,000) 75%,
        rgb(255,000,000) 100%
    );
}
<div></div>




Due to the limited number of stops, the resulting render is a bit blocky, but the overall gradient does look noticeably better than the default. Adding even more stops does improve it even more:


div {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, 
        rgb(000,255,000),
        rgb(090,239,000) 12.5%,
        rgb(127,221,000) 25%,
        rgb(156,201,000) 37.5%,
        rgb(180,180,000) 50%,
        rgb(201,156,000) 62.5%,
        rgb(221,127,000) 75%,
        rgb(239,090,000) 87.5%,
        rgb(255,000,000) 100%
    );
}
<div></div>




My question is, is there a way to achieve a more continuous gradient like this in CSS (either vanilla or by using some other tool)?

i could get something closer with filter:blur and zoom:, but nothing clean enough to post. Aside: If your steps are evenly-spaced, you don't need to explicitly list the %s, which cleans it up slightly...

Using a polar colourspace with interpolation can give better results.


div {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    background: linear-gradient(
      to right in oklch shorter hue,
      rgb(0,255,0),
      rgb(255,0,0)
    );
}
<div></div>




you don't need shorter hue, it's the default path
